# How to read the expression in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to digest below expression of LISP, I am confused at the part of equal expression

```lisp
(cond ((= a 4 ) 6 )
      ((= b 4 ) ( + 6 7 a ))
      (else 25) )
```

Particularly conditional predicate `(= a 4 ) 6`

Thank you

Comment: nvm, seems lisp equality operator is `=` instead of `==` which is usual.

Comment: There are a host of equality operators in Common Lisp: `eq`, `eql`, `equal`, `equalp`, `=`, and others. `=` is for checking numeric equality. Note that `else` is not used in Common Lisp, rather `t` is used, i.e., `(cond ((= a 4) 6) ((= b 4) (+ 6 7 a)) (t 25))`.

Comment: yes, you are right. else is not used on common lisp

Comment: Common Lisp uses `=` to compare numbers for equality, just like in maths.

Answer (score 2):

`cond` is a way to do `if-elseif-else` in lisp languages.

```
(cond 
  ((= a 4 ) 6)
  ((= b 4 ) (+ 6 7 a))
  (t 25))               ; CL uses t (Scheme has else)
```

Is the same as:

```
(if (= a 4)
    6
    (if (= b 4)
        (+ 6 7 a)
        25))
```

And quite litteraly since [`cond` is specified as a macro](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_cond.htm).
In a typical Algol language, like Python one would write that as:

```
if (a == 4):
  6
elif (b == 4):
  a + 6 + 7
else:
  25
```

Note that CL doesn't need `return` and it does it in any context. The example above works in the Python REPL, not everywhere like with CL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `else`, but it's not common: you would need to set the symbol `else` to `T`.

```
CL-USER 18 > (defvar else t)
ELSE

CL-USER 19 > (cond ((< 4 3) 'one)
                   (else 'two))
TWO
```

Answer (score 0):

To correctly read Lisp code, you must consider the entire top-level expression and work from the outside in. For the present purposes, top-level expression means "expression not enclosed in another expression".

Lisp is a programmable language in which new operators can be defined which process their contents under their own rules. If you start reading an expression somewhere in the middle, you could miss the fact that the very top level operator has changed the meaning of the entire top-level expression in such a way that your reading is completely incorrect.

For instance:

```
(+ a b)
```

means add the values of `a` and `b`, producing their sum, right? But what if that is enclosed in another operator:

```
(defun f (+ a b))
```

Now `(+ a b)` is a parameter list, expressing the fact that `f` has three parameters named `+`, `a` and `b`.

You have to start on the outside.

When you get more familiar with Lisp, and familiar with a code base that you're reading (perhaps because you wrote it yourself), you can take shortcuts.

Assuming that your `cond` is a top-level expression, or an expression that occurs in a context where it is a form (expression evaluated for its value), we can start by looking at it from the outside: it invokes the `cond` operator. From that we know that

```
((= a 4 ) 6 )
```

is a `cond` clause. The first expression `(= a 4)` is a test expression which is evaluated. If that test succeeds, then the second expression `6` will be evaluated and that will be the result of the `cond`: `cond` will not evaluate any more clauses.

In `cond`, an unconditionally successful test is usually written as `t`. Any constant expression that evaluates true would also work. Such a test is often the basis for the last clause in a `cond`, in order to execute "fallback" code for when none of the cases matched.

The `else` symbol can only work instead of `t` if you defined that as a macro or variable yourself:

```
[1]> (defconstant else t)
ELSE
[2]> (cond (else 1))
1
```

This is unidiomatic; I am not recommending it.

In the early history of Lisp, over half a century ago, the `T` symbol was actually defined as a variable, so `T` in a `COND` clause worked much the same way as my `else` variable above. Today, over half a century later, `T` is a self-evaluating symbol, and not a variable.

When `COND` was first defined over half a century ago, its arguments were strictly pairs and were called "cond pairs". In Common Lisp, the clauses are not pairs: they are lists of one or more expression.

If the clause has only one expression, and that expression evaluates true, then `cond` will stop and yield that value.  A clause may have one, two, three or more elements.

Thus `(cond (42))` yields 42!

The `or` operator can be rewritten to `cond` with one-element clauses, therefore:

```
(or a b c d ...)   <-->   (cond (a) (b) (c) (d) ...)
```